# Is it possible to disable client request(cqlsh) to cassandra without stopping cassandra service?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

tried with below,

**nodetool disablethrift**

Do I need to configure something extra?

Comment: Why do you want that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra supports two different protocols for clients connecting to the database: thrift and the cql binary protocol. The thrift interface is deprecated and will eventually be removed. Modern client libraries use the cql binary protocol (including cqlsh).

To cause cassandra to stop accepting clients using the cql binary protocol you can run:

```
nodetool disablebinary
```